# Reading remote IP from UDP packets received by another application

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, h.323

I'm writing an app to deploy on our machines to force the user to enter statistics about h323 video use.

I want to get a maximum of information without asking the user, I'm having some trouble getting the remote IP address for point-to-point connection using a gatekeeper (no TCP connection to the remote IP).

I thought multiple apps could read the same UDP, but I get a socketException when I try to read the proper port. I'm using a UDPClient and get the error when I try to create the client on an active port.

Any suggestion on how to do this without having to install WinPcap and use pcap.net ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you all on the same internal network?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting the address already in use exception? To allow multiple UDPClients to use the same port set the [ExclusiveAddressUse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.exclusiveaddressuse(v=vs.100).aspx) property to false:

```
myUdpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
```